# Custom python module in azure databricks with spark/dbutils dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I recently swicthed on the preview feature "files in repos" on Azure Databricks, so that I could move a lot of my general functions from notebooks to modules and get rid of the overhead from running a lot of notebooks for a single job.

However, several of my functions rely directly on dbutils or spark/pyspark functions (e.g. `dbutils.secrets.get()` and `spark.conf.set()`). Since these are imported in the background for the notebooks and are tied directly to the underlying session, I am at complete loss as to how I can reference these modules in my custom modules.

For my small sample module, I fixed it by making dbutils a parameter, like in the following example:

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, dbutils):
        token = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="my-scope", key="mykey")
        ...
```

However, doing this for all the existing functions would require a significant amount of rewriting both the functions and the lines that call them. How can I avoid this procedure and do it in a more clean manner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation for Databricks Connect shows the example](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#access-dbutils) how it could be achieved.  That example has `SparkSession` as an explicit parameter, but it could be modified to avoid that completely, with something like this:

```py
def get_dbutils():
  from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
  if spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.client.enabled") == "true":
    from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
    return DBUtils(spark)
  else:
    import IPython
    return IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
```

and then in your function you can do something like this:

```py
def get_my_secret(scope, key):
  return get_dbutils().secrets.get(scope, key)
```