# using dbutils (dbutils.fs.rm in a databricks Job) azure databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html

I am trying to use `dbutils.fs.rm` in a job for Azure on a dbfs folder. It's actually a big pain and the `dbutils.fs.rm` resolves all the issues but seems to only work in a notebook.

The issues I am having are dealing with sub folders with files. I want an easy way within python to delete all a folder, and all sub content.

Comment: Can you use an azure function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom python module in azure databricks with spark/dbutils dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420828/custom-python-module-in-azure-databricks-with-spark-dbutils-dependencies)

Comment: sadly if I had access, I would. my guess is that there is a sync or cache situation going on.