# How to automatically pass spark and dbutils to .py file in Databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have my main notebook in databricks that I am running my base set of code. Right now, I have to always pass "spark" and "dbutils" through my function to get the function to work properly.

Main notebook code:

```
from subfolder import awesome

awesome.somefunction(spark,dbutils,parameterC)
```

The code within the awesome.py file is the following: (this is located in a folder called "subfolder" which is one level deeper than the main notebook, it is also accompanied by an init python file)

```
def somefunction(spark,dbutils,parameterC):
    # used spark in this function
    # used dbutils in this function
    # used parameterC in this function
    # create a spark view at the end
    # return None
    return None
```

If I remove spark and dbutils from the function, I get the "spark" or "dbutils" module has not been found.

How can I get it so I don't have to automatically pass spark and dbutils to my .py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Databricks, `spark` and `dbutils` are automatically injected only into the main entrypoint - your notebook, but they aren't propagated to the Python modules.  With `spark` solution is easy, just use the `getActiveSession` function of `SparkSession` class (as `SparkSession.getActiveSession()`), but you need to continue to pass `dbutils` explicitly until you don't abstract getting `dbutils` into some function, like, described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420828/custom-python-module-in-azure-databricks-with-spark-dbutils-dependencies/71421796#71421796).