# Github Actions: Problem with dbutils when running pytest

Tags: pyspark, pytest, azure-databricks, dbutils

I am trying to run a pytest using a function from my main code with Github Actions.
My main code as a `dbutils.widgets` that cause my pytest crashing.

On my first iteration I got the error:

```
`NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined`
```

So in my pytest file I added following lines of code and also pip installed `pyspark` in my Github Acrtions workflow before running pystest:

```
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
dbutils = DBUtils(spark_session)
```

But I still got an error. From Github Actions log:

```
    from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.dbutils`
```

This is strange because it successfully installed pyspark in the previous step.

How can I solve this dbutil issue? I don't even need it for my pytest.

Comment: could you please share code with which you install pyspark? Also, try to make sure you're installing it in the same python env as you're running your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `dbutils` isn't a part of PySpark - it's a Databricks-specific functionality and is available when a code is running on Databricks. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420828/custom-python-module-in-azure-databricks-with-spark-dbutils-dependencies/71421796#71421796) shows how you can work around this issue.

Comment: Im not sure how I should use `get_dbutils()`. Should I implement it in pytest code somehow?

Comment: No. Instead of using dbutils directly in your code you need to switch to dbutils

Comment: I did according the example you provided but now I get another error due to `spark.conf`: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'conf'**

Comment: You need to use spark_session instead

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more please? I have tried `spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()` without success